# chaincore is there anybody succeed to build a new blockchain by using chaincore

Tags: blockchain

I am looking into https://chain.com/docs/1.1/core/learn-more/blockchain-operators#creating-a-new-blockchain to build a new block chain. 
To build this, I first create a docker compose file to create generator and signer. The docker composer file is below:

```
version: '2'
services: 
  generator:
    image: chaincore/developer:1.1.0
    container_name: generator
    ports:
      - 1999:1999
  signer:
    image: chaincore/developer:1.1.0
    container_name: signer
    ports:
      - 1998:1999
```

Step1 start container by using the docker-compose.yml 
docker-compose up -d

Step2 login into generator website, and configure the generator as "create new blockchain network"

Step3 ssh login into signer, and execute 
/usr/bin/chain/corectl create-block-keypair 
/usr/bin/chain/corectl create-token -net foo

Step4 ssh login into generator, and execute 
/usr/bin/chain/corectl config-generator 1 45ec61ecf456cd114e88baaf5f4cf6d5d62a666d7b2f17a6e49f6da124921923 http://foo:f4fc3cc08932cfef1936b8bc41805458ea3e9a085ccbc6468262fca3de5178c0@192.168.222.50:1998 
, and get error 
error: storing block: insert block: pq: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "blocks_height_key"

Answer (score 1):

I have made it work. I made a mistake on step2. Just ignore step2, then you can success.